# JBoss Fuse 6.1: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl could not be instantiated

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, jaxp

> Environment: JBoss Fuse 6.1 Fabric.

I have a Camel processor where I am trying to instantiate a DocumentBuilderFactory within my java code using

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

And for some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle is uninstalled
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:110)
    at com.cigna.dom.util.DocumentUtils.getDocumentBuilder(DocumentUtils.java:464)
    at com.cigna.dom.util.DocumentUtils.createDocument(DocumentUtils.java:489)
    at com.cigna.commons.schema.XmlSchemaUtil.documentFromSchema(XmlSchemaUtil.java:70)
    at com.cigna.camel.processor.response.DOMResponseProcessor.process(DOMResponseProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
```

I am not sure which bundle is uninstalled here. I tried adding the following bundle to features.xml but of no use.

```
<bundle dependency="true" start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces/2.11.0_1</bundle>
```

This error is not happening all the time. It is very sporadic and sometimes it goes away after restarting the Fuse container.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.